# Scrollviewer and Manipulation events

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have `ListView` and `Grid`. I have taken `ListView's` `ScrollViewer` through `VisualTreeHelper` and added `ViewChanged` event handler.In event handler I have disabled `VerticalScrollMode` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` if vertical offset is set to 0 to perform manipulation event. I'm trying to access manipulation events but its not firing. Please suggest me.

```
 <Grid ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta">
                <ListView  x:Name="list" >
                    <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
                </ListView>
                </Grid>

private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
}

public MainPage()
{
    var content = list.GetChildrenOfType<ScrollViewer>();
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = content.First() as ScrollViewer; 
    scrollViewer.ViewChanged += Content_ViewChanged;
}

private void Content_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as ScrollViewer).VerticalOffset == 0)
    {
        (sender as ScrollViewer).VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to help you without seeing your code

Comment: Could you show more detail about the extension method of `GetChildrenOfType`?

Comment: static IEnumerable<T> GetChildrenOfType<T>(this DependencyObject start) where T : class  {var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
            queue.Enqueue(start);
            while (queue.Count > 0)  { var item = queue.Dequeue();
                var realItem = item as T;  if (realItem != null)
                {yield return realItem;
                }

                int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(item);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {              queue.Enqueue(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(item, i));}